# Asp.net core application deploy as exe

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-7

I create new application with asp.net core .net framework 4.6.1 not core2 .
When I build application or deploy its relased as .exe not dll.

below is web.config for publish folder :

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\Projectxxx.Upload.exe" 
    stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"/></system.webServer>
```

**Is that mean the project is out process ?**

Also if I get any error give me this message

**HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure**

**I want to make the project in process and run at windows platform only what can be do for that ?**

Any help
this is my project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-Projectxxx.Upload-332B348E-4A41-4FF3-A789-DD081E38AE8A</UserSecretsId>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.1</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.6" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.Administration" Version="11.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: At least modify the question to include your project file, as well as the actual error page.

Comment: i insert project file and my issue , i want make project in process .

Comment: When you set it as out-of-process, your IIS act as a proxy. So you need to set its port to the same as your asp.net core port number. If you want your asp.net core host as in-process, when don't you just select framework dependent in visual studio web deployment profile.

Comment: i dont set any setting for in or out of process i want application to be in process .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"The in-process hosting model isn't supported for ASP.NET Core apps that target the .NET Framework."**

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#in-process-hosting-model)

Comment: that mean the application with asp.net core target .net framework is always is out of process ?  and to solve this i should go to MVC 5 applications !!